# Ubuntu 12.04 freezes when booting

Tags: 12.04, boot, screen

**Translated**

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from the LiveCD, after finalizing the installation process and booting correctly, I applied the pending updates, which asked me to reboot. After rebooting, an error appeared saying "Out of Range". I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login to the tty1 terminal and edit the **xorg.conf** file and add `VertRefresh 50.0 - 60.0` to it, which would solve the "Out of Range" problem that was mentioned before. After applying the changed and rebooting again, the following boot screen is all I see now:

[image]

It freezes there. I even waited 2 hours and nothing happened.

Can anybody help?

Thank you!

**Original**

Instale Ubuntu 12.04 LTS desde el Live CD, al finalizar la instalación inicio el sistema operativo e inicia correctamente, después de aplicar actualizaciones me solicita reiniciar en lo cual acepto.
Al volver a iniciar me daba un erro de "Fuera de rango", aprieto CTRL + ALT + F1, me logueo y edito el archivo xorg.conf en la sección Screen y agrego "VertRefresh 50.0 - 60.0", lo cual solucionaría el problema de "Fuera de rango", al aplicar los cambios, vuelvo a iniciar y solamente me aparece la pantalla de inicio (Véase imagen: http://t.bb/fH) y queda colgado, lo deje por lo menos 2 horas así y nada sucedió.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Gracias!

Comment: Please translate your question to English language, because it is the language used by this site.

Comment: Sorry.
Ready!!!

Comment: I have taken the liberty of translating it to better English than Google Translate.

Comment: Sorry, my English is bad :(

Comment: @AgustínGonzález - Me da curiosidad que la imagen dice Lucid Lynx. Es esto en realidad la 12.04?. BTW porque fuistes directo a editar xorg.conf. Es por tu monitor/TV?, tu tarjeta de video. DE todos modos en ese caso, deja presionado SHIFT hasta que salga el menu de GRUB. Alli selecciona la opcion que deseas bootear y presionas E. busca la linea que termina con "quiet splash" y quita esas dos opciones. Arranca el sistema presionando F10 (Creo que es F10 de todos modos GRUB te dice cual es) y el sistema te podra decir que debes hacer. Es necesario estos datos para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Luis, la imagen es una representacion del boot screen.
Estuve buscando informacion sobre porque el error de "Out of range" y encontre que debiendo modificar xorg.conf podria ingresar el refresco de mi monitor, el cual soporta 50-60Hz. Voy a probar lo que me dices, gracias.

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste y al apretar F10 o CTRL + X simplemente me lleva al logueo "boot", no se como decirtelo porque no se como se le dice.

Answer (score 0):

deberias reinstalar, que especificaciones tiene tu compu ? D: la verdad nunca me ha pasado eso pero debe de ser algo que esta mal instalado , ammm si estas conectado a internet por cable prueba metiendo las actualizaciones por linea de comandos aver si actualizandolo lo soluciona siempre me ha funcionado eso

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Hola, tengo 500GB de disco, 30GB reservado para Ubuntu, 4GB de RAM, MotherBoard: Gigabyte M68MT-S2P. Ya reinstale y al actualizar vuelve a pasar lo mismo, y si, las actualizaciones las descarga, estoy conectado por Wi-Fi y reconoce bien la conexion.

Comment: Probe lo de actualizar y sigue igual.

Comment: que raro por que eso deveria funcionar :/ , si entras en modo consola no se por que no te deja entrar al modo grafico, aunque deverias de poner tambien tu tarjeta grafica y pues instalar los drivers propietarios :B